# sysout redirected to swing console, log4j content won´t

Tags: java, log4j

I have the console output redirected to a swing console. When I add a sysout to the code, the text appears in the swing component.
Now I thought that my console output from log4j would also appear in this swing component. But any log.info() message still appears in the eclipse console.
When I debug my Handeler who redirects the messages to the swing component, I can see that the logger's messages do not pass by there. Sysout messages however do.

Can anyone give me a hint what might be going wrong here? Can I have two consoles at the same time?

Here is my config for log4j:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filtro=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filtro.levelMin=ALL
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filtro.levelMax=FATAL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple but hard to track. I used the Logger in the GUI class in which I had the console component. So I guess the Logger was initialized before the code that redirected it to the swing console was executed. When this code was executed, as gthe Logger was already set up, it stayed the way it was.

When I removed the logger from the GUI class, everything worked fine.